# Execute load and change together jQuery

Tags: jquery, onload

I have a js function that shows different messages when an option from select is clicked.
I am using `.onchange` to fire the messages.

What I am trying to achieve as well is to show the correct message if you load the HTML and an option is already selected. So somehow I guess to combine change and load.

**Here is my HTML**

```
<div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="cat">Category</label>
                            <select name="cat" id="cat" class="form-control" size="5">
                                <option value="General">General</option>
                                <option value="Rooms">Rooms</option>
                                <option value="Restaurant">Restaurant</option>
                                <option value="Spa">Spa</option>
                                <option value="Massages" selected>Massages</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="form-group"><label for="cat">Category explanation</label>
                            <div class="alert alert-secondary show_general" style="display:none;"><strong>General: </strong>The general category </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-secondary show_rooms" style="display:none;"><strong>Rooms: </strong>The rooms category </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-secondary show_restaurant" style="display:none;"><strong>Restaurant: </strong>The </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-secondary show_spa" style="display:none;"><strong>Spa: </strong>The Spa category </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-secondary show_massages" style="display:none;"><strong>Massages: </strong>The massages category carousel </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

**The JS**

```
$('#cat').on('change load',function load_msg() {

  if ($(this).val() == 'General') { $('.show_general').show(); } else { $('.show_general').hide(); }
  if ($(this).val() == 'Rooms') { $('.show_rooms').show(); } else { $('.show_rooms').hide(); }
  if ($(this).val() == 'Spa') { $('.show_spa').show(); } else { $('.show_spa').hide(); }
  if ($(this).val() == 'Restaurant') { $('.show_restaurant').show(); } else { $('.show_restaurant').hide(); }
  if ($(this).val() == 'Massages') { $('.show_massages').show(); } else { $('.show_massages').hide(); }

});
```

I have tried to use `.onload` together with `change` but can't figure out why it is not working

Comment: Note that there is a [`toggle`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) function that takes a Boolean, so you could rewrite code to, for example, `$('.show_general').toggle($(this).val() == 'General');`.

Comment: Thanks for that approach too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of triggering onload, you need to trigger the .change() event of the dropdown. This triggers the same function as if someone selected/changed the dropdown. I have also optimized the code.

```
$('#cat').on('change',function load_msg() {
   $('.alert-secondary').hide();
   $('.show_'+ $(this).val().toLowerCase()).show();
});

$('#cat').change();
```

Comment: Wow, that is so simple and working perfectly. Also, the part with taking the value that is after the show_ , and making it dynamic Is great. Thanks a lot!